# App Store wants to install Public Beta 3 but I’m no longer in the Beta Program?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, beta-seed-program, beta

I used to be in the beta program before Sierra came out, but I have since un-enrolled.

I don’t have the beta profile in my App Store settings as mentioned [here](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll) but the App Store still wants to update me to 10.12.2 Public Beta 3. I am currently on 10.12.1 (stable).

Does anyone know how I can prevent the App Store from showing beta updates?

Comment: @fsb no as this is for macOs and that will differ from iOS

Comment: You're correct, @Mark, my mistake.  I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

After you uninstall the Beta Profile, you need to reboot your device for the change to take effect.